# Mongo Database query - retrieving all documents that has an equality to a value in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

Is there a way to retrieve all the documents (MONGOSH) which has an objectID in the filmsReviewed array equal to 6405429fd07c188c61461a8b?

[image]

This is not working

```
db.users.find({filmsReviewed:{$elemMatch:{ObjectId("6405429fd07c188c61461a8b")}}})
```

Comment: you are querying `filmsCreated` while the field in the document is `filemsReviewed`? If the field name is corrected, you can just do something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/r8wv37TEZOq)

Comment: What does `not working` mean?  If that means you are getting back an empty result,  try running `db.getName()` to make sure you are in the database you expect.